# Flutter: Version solving failed in pub get

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-pub, flutter-pubspec

### Situation

I just cloned a Flutter project in which my colleagues are working on, but I cannot make it work on my laptop. I am using a Macbook Pro, the same as them. It works for them, but not for me.

The problem is at `flutter pub get` or `flutter upgrade`. This is the error:

> Resolving dependencies...
>
> Note: intl is pinned to version 0.18.1 by flutter_localizations from the flutter SDK.
> See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.
>
> **Because trooms depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.1, intl 0.18.1 is required.
> So, because trooms depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.**
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

And these are my dependencies:

```
name: trooms
description: Web, Android and iOS App for TROOMS.
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
    
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  intl: 0.18.1
  json_serializable: ^6.1.6
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0
  firebase_core: ^2.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.6
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.6
  firebase_performance: ^0.9.0+6
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.6
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  flutter_image_slideshow: ^0.1.4
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.5
  logging: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.1.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.0+2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  beamer: ^1.5.3
  q_form:
    git:
      url: //url
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.5
  date_time_picker: ^2.1.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.5
  flutter_beacon: ^0.5.1
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_app_name: ^0.1.1
  build_runner: ^2.1.10
  fake_cloud_firestore: ^2.0.1
  firebase_auth_mocks: ^0.9.1
  firebase_storage_mocks: ^0.6.0+1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  get: ^4.6.1

flutter_app_name:
  name: "TROOMS"

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/trooms-ulm-logo.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: #ffffff
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
  - assets/
  - assets/icon/
```

### First attempted solution

I tried changing the SDK to the same as them but it did not work. I can't downgrade Flutter to their exact same version, for some reason:

> ```
> ~ TROOMS % flutter downgrade v3.7.7
>
> Downgrade flutter to version 3.3.9
>
> ? [y|n]:
> ```

### Second attempted solution

Then, I changed the intl package version to the one required: `intl: 0.18.1`. This is the new error with that:

> Resolving dependencies...
>
> Because date_time_picker 2.1.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and no versions of date_time_picker match >2.1.0 <3.0.0, date_time_picker ^2.1.0 requires intl ^0.17.0.
> So, because trooms depends on both intl 0.18.1 and date_time_picker ^2.1.0, version solving failed.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

### Third attempted solution

I also tried changing `flutter_localizations` to any like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: any
```

But it's also not accepted:

> Resolving dependencies...
>
> Because trooms depends on flutter_localizations any which doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_localizations at https://pub.dev), version solving failed.
>
> Process finished with exit code 69

I did the same for `intl`. Same output.

### Questions

So it seems that the packages `date_time_picker` and `flutter_localizations` **both depend on different versions of intl**, which is not compatible and that's why it fails. So, how can I solve packages having different pinned versions of the same dependency?

BUT why I'm confused is because the exact same code **does work** for my colleages, having the same dependencies, although we do have different SDKs. Could the SDK have something to do?

Comment: try `flutter_localizations:any`

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh oh sorry, I also tried that already and it didn't work. I edited the question and added the error message

Comment: Can you please try to downgrade flutter_localizations version who depends on intl version ^0.17.0.Also change intl version to ^0.17.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from **Flutter >= 3.10** (do some research yourself to be sure), *flutter_localizations* require *intl >= 0.18.0*. So there's 2 solutions:

- if *date_time_picker* has a version which use newer version of Flutter, use it instead,
- downgrade your Flutter SDK to a version that support *intl 0.17.0*.

Comment: Thanks! I downgraded the sdk to a version that requires the same version of intl and now it works, but I don't think this should be a long-term solution